# Could I compare to zero register in avx correctly?

Tags: c, avx

I have met a very strange behavior of AVX intrinsic instruction _mm256_testc_pd().
Here you can see a description of this function https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&text=test&expand=5432

I used it in my code 2 times expected to see a similar results of comparison something to zero register.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char arr[32] __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));

    __m256d a, zero;
    int res1, res2;

    memset(arr, 0 , 32);
    arr[0] = 0xff;
    arr[4] = 0xff;
    arr[8] = 0xff;
    arr[12] = 0xff;
    arr[16] = 0xff;
    arr[20] = 0xfd;
    arr[24] = 0xff;
    arr[28] = 0xff;


    zero = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    a = _mm256_load_pd((double *)arr);
    res1 = _mm256_testc_pd(zero, a);
    printf("res1 = %d\n" , res1);

    memset(arr, 0xff, 32);
    a = _mm256_load_pd((double *)arr);
    res2 =  _mm256_testc_pd(zero, a);
    printf("res2 = %d\n" , res2);
    return 0;
}
```

As a result I got

```
res1 = 1
res2 = 0
```

Does anyone understand why it's happened? I think in both cases `a` not equals to zero.

**UPDATE**
After a discussion in comments my problem was solved but i have a little misunderstanding in functions _mm256_testc_si256 and _mm256_testz_si256

For example:

```
unsigned char arr[32] __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));

    __m256d a, zero;

    int res1, res2;
    memset(arr, 0 , 32);

    arr[0] = 0x80;

    zero = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    a = _mm256_load_pd((double *)arr);

    res1 = _mm256_testc_si256(_mm256_castpd_si256(zero),_mm256_castpd_si256(a));
    res2 = _mm256_testz_si256(_mm256_castpd_si256(zero),_mm256_castpd_si256(a));
    printf("res1 = %d\n" , res1);
    printf("res2 = %d\n" , res2);
```

Output was

```
res1 = 0
res2 = 1
```

And i think only first one is correct. So why this functions produce different output?

Comment: Just asing `arr[20] = 0xfd;` is this intentional?

Comment: It doesn't matter , it may be `0xff`, same behavior.

Comment: Does this instruction really do what you expect it to do? I'd rather say that you want to use _mm256_cmp_pd() to compare values.

Comment: I think you are right, but do you know what should be in 3rd argument of _mm256_cmp_pd () ?

Comment: @AlekseyM: you can just pass `_CMP_EQ_OQ` (== `0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_mm256_testc_pd` operates only on the *sign bit* of each double precision element, so the observed behaviour is correct. If you want to test double precision *values* in each element then use a suitable compare instruction first (e.g. `_mm256_cmp_pd` with appropriate `_CMP_xxx` parameter) and then use `_mm256_testc_pd` or `_mm256_testz_pd` afterwards, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me alot

Comment: while thinking on this problem, i also use the cast instruction and integer comparison, it is also helps me `_mm256_testc_si256(_mm256_castpd_si256(zero), _mm256_castpd_si256(a)) `
May be it will be useful for someone.

Comment: @AlekseyM: you have to be careful with using integer compares for this, as there are two different 0 values in IEEE-754 (0 and -0), either of which should compare equal to 0. Using an integer compare will fail for -0.

Comment: @AlekseyM:  You could test for FP zero using integer `PTEST` by testing against a mask that had all but the sign-bit set.  e.g. `ones=_mm256_cmpeq_epi64(same, same);  testmask=_mm256_srli_epi64(ones, 1);  return _mm256_testz_si256(a, ones);`  That tests for non-zero bits anywhere except the sign-bit positions.  I wouldn't recommend this special-case optimization for practical use, though!

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I need the code witch will return 1 if at lest  one bit in AVX register not zero (it doesnt matter sign bit or not). I think compare to ones is not a good solution in this case.

Comment: @Paul R: if I use _mm256_testc_si256() for compare 0 and, for example, -0, will i get that they are equal? do you know how looks -0 in hex  as long long?  It is really important for me, if testing -0 for ones will return "no ones"

Comment: @AlekseyM: the only difference between 0.0 and -0.0 is the sign bit: `0.0` = `0x000...000`, `-0.0` = `0x800...000`.

Comment: @AlekseyM: If you want to test for any set bits in the whole register, use `_mm256_testz_si256(a, a)`, just like you would use `test eax, eax / jz` on an integer register.  Make sure you really do want to treat `-0` differently from `0` in your function.  If you're sure, then this is the most direct way to check for any non-zero bits in the binary representation of the FP values.

Comment: @AlekseyM: You're testing against `zero`, not against itself.  `PTEST` (`testz_si256`) does an AND between its args, and sets the `z` flag if all the bits are zero.  It also does `src1 AND (NOT src2)` and sets the `c` flag if all bits in that are zero.  Your `testc` is *always* going to be zero, regardless of `a`.  edit: I think you deleted your comment right before I finished typing.  :P

Comment: @AlekseyM: you can edit comments for up to 5 minutes, instead of deleting and messing up the ordering.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are right, but It was inconvenient to example code in comments, so I updated the question. Can you explain what happens in my updated code.

Comment: @AlekseyM: I already did, while you were deleting / reposting your comments!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072169/could-i-compare-to-zero-register-in-avx-correctly/32073056?noredirect=1#comment52129460_32073056  Just read the manual for the function on the intrinsics guide, or the Intel insn ref manual

Comment: @PeterCordes: According to Intel intrinsics guide 
int _mm256_testz_si256 (__m256i a, __m256i b)

IF (a[255:0] AND b[255:0] == 0) 
  ZF := 1 
ELSE 
  ZF := 0 
FI

return ZF
So i will get 0 always when one of the arguments is zero, and it doesnt help me to determine presence of ones in register

Comment: @AlekseyM: you don't need to explicitly test against 0, just use the example Peter gave earlier, i.e. `_mm256_testz_si256(a, a)` - it's more efficient (doesn't require a zero vector) and more intuitive/readable.

Comment: @PaulR : Oh, I got it, and it works. thanks. But why does my version `res1 = _mm256_testc_si256(_mm256_castpd_si256(zero), _mm256_castpd_si256(a))` work correctly too? According to intrinsics guide, it shouldn't.

Comment: @AlekseyM: Peter explained that in the comments above also: the `testc` version tests `src1 AND (NOT src2)` (although it looks like you may have the arguments the wrong way around ?).

Comment: @PaulR:  I understand that, but what really confuse me that in exact this arguments order - first `zero`, second `a` it works correctly. Whereas in "logical" order - first `a`, second `zero` it doesnt work correctly. May be intel made a mistake)) in description or in implementation? (yeah sounds incredible)

Comment: @AlekseyM: Yeah, it does look like your test is showing the `testc` intrinsic's description is wrong.  If the order of the args matches the order `PTEST` uses, in Intel/MASM syntax, then it is the first arg that's inverted.  (And yes, that is a valid way to do the test.  It also makes it possible for the compiler to fold a memory operand into the PTEST instruction in a loop, if one of the operands is constant.  `_mm_testz` with an all-ones vector from a `pcmpeq`, or `mm_testc` with an all-zero vector from `_mm_setzero`.)  I wonder if anyone's noticed this documentation bug before!

Comment: I seem to remember that some of the gcc headers when AVX was new had a few bugs in them, particularly in regard to transposed operands etc - it's possible the OP has an old gcc installation. Also it's worth checking against `_mm_testc_pd`, as there should at least be consistency between the SSE and AVX versions.

Comment: @PaulR: The behaviour matches what you'd get from `PTEST` with args in that order, so I think it's a doc bug in the intrinsics guide, *not* a compiler / header bug.  I'm reporting it now on the Intel forum thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes it is really interesting observation.) Thanks for so deep investigation. Please show me a link to  that forum thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes: it could easily be a documentation bug (or possibly a header/intrinsics bug) - the `testc` variant is very rarely used (in my experience, at least) whereas the `testz` version is used a lot (and behaves the same regardless of operand order anyway).

Comment: @PeterCordes: looking at the Intel manuals I think I can see where the confusion comes from - the description for PTEST *et al* says (paraphrasing) `CF = SRC AND NOT DEST`, but `DEST` is typically the first input parameter in the intrinsic, so the `testc` intrinsics are doing `param2 AND NOT param1`.

Comment: @AlekseyM: The link is there from the ? next to the search box in the guide.  I didn't find it right away either. :P  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/363747?page=2#comment-1836122.  "Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval."

Comment: @PaulR: yes, exactly.  And the intrinsics guide documents `testc` as doing `NOT param2`, which is the doc bug I reported.  I'm not surprised to hear you say `testc` is almost never used.  Interesting that you can test C and Z flags to see if a vector had a mix of ones and zeroes, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: well done for reporting this - it's interesting to note that `PANDN`/`_mm_andnot_si128` has similar semantics but they seem to have got this right in the Intrinsics Guide.

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks for reporting. I hope in future  we will see right description in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Cordes and all others, The correct (and most beautiful) solution for my problem was

`res = _mm256_testz_si256(_mm256_castpd_si256(a), _mm256_castpd_si256(a))`